# How to Share a link from Chrome in my React Native app in a specific Modal/Screen

Tags: react-native, linkshare

I want to share links in my app from any other app like Chrome, Facebook, or LinkedIn. But I could not find any solution. Kindly give me a proper solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean you want to make a preview link like this: https://andrejgajdos.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/link-preview-result-1024x478.png?

Comment: Yes, it is. How can I do?

Comment: Did you try this? : https://github.com/flyerhq/react-native-link-preview